# variable naming conventions for when desired name is already defined

Tags: naming-conventions

Is there a convention for naming a variable when the name you want is already defined by the language? As an example, I'm currently coding a lisp function that takes two parameters, min and max. Vim's syntax highlighter colors those words though, so it looks like they're already lisp functions. I assume it'd be better to give the parameters different names.

Should I use completely different names? min and max are both short and descriptive though, so I'd like to use them if possible. Should I use a prefix, like myMin and myMax? I'm currently leaning towards that idea. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Interested to see what everyone says about this...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a very general naming convention - the one that would work well with *all* names reserved/defined in your language or framework - I really doubt that such convention would be practical or even useful.

I think you should do it on a (common) case by case basis.

Your example looks like one of such common cases: it probably is quite common for functions to have two parameters specifying some range of values. Well, in that case, I'd probably go with names like `minValue` and `maxValue` - they seem to be abstract enough to work well in most situations.

BTW, I would not use a prefix like `my`. However, if you were open to the idea of Apps Hungarian (see [discussion on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian) and [Joel Spolsky's article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html)), the answer to your question would be much simpler: just use a proper semantic prefix in the names of your parameters (e.g. `xMin` and `xMax` for min and max abscissa values).